# How can I scrape data if "div name" like this "_ngcontent-ijy-c118"

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try ;

1 ) `article_name = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'_ngcontent-ijy-c117 class':'List-results-items'})`

2 ) `article_name = soup.find_all('div _ngcontent-ijy-c117',attrs={' class':'List-results-items'})`

3 ) `article_name = soup.find_all('div',attrs={' class':'List-results-items'})`

not working.
thaks
[[image: 1]]

Comment: Cause question is not that clear, some more details and HTML as text instead of image would improve it. May take a minute or two to read: [ask] and How to create [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by class works well:

```
soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'List-results-items'})
```

or

```
soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'List-results-items'})
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup='''
<div _ngcontent-ijy-c117 class="List-results-items">some text</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(soup)

soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'List-results-items'})
```

###### Output

```
<div _ngcontent-ijy-c117="" class="List-results-items">some text</div>
```

---

Just in case it looks like you have to iterate your `ResultSet` to get each of your articles. Example->

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup='''
<div _ngcontent-ijy-c117 class="List-results-items">
    <a>Article One<a/>
    <a>Article Two<a/>
    <a>Article Three<a/>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(soup)

for e in soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'List-results-items'}).find_all('a'):
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I try to scrape this website. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=(%22Full%20Text%20.AND.%20Metadata%22:Image%20Processing)    I try your code but not working. Thanks

Comment: To keep the post clean - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and some more details as mentioned - Content is generated dynamically and you have to use selenium or requests_html